# Avoiding readout race conditions in event log tables

Tags: postgresql

Suppose we have a simple table in PostgreSQL database:

```
+========================+
|       event_log        |
+----+-----------+-------+
| id | stream_id | event |
+====+===========+=======+
|  1 |         1 | aaa   |
|  2 |         1 | bbb   |
|  3 |         2 | ccc   |
|  4 |         1 | ddd   |
+====+===========+=======+
```

Remote system fetches new updates by running a query similar to:

```sql
SELECT * FROM event_log WHERE stream_id = ? AND id > ?
```

Remote system persists last known event ID and uses it to skip already processed parts of event stream.

**Now, the race condition itself:** when you run concurrent inserts on the log table you have a problem: ID generation sequence may differ from transaction commit sequence, e.g.:

```
   TX A  |   TX B   |   TX C 
---------+----------+-----------
INSERT 5 |          |   
         | INSERT 6 | 
         | COMMIT   |
         |          | SELECT 6
COMMIT   |          |
```

In this scenario remote system will never receive event #5 since it already saw event #6. So systems will eventually go out of sync.

Is there any well-known efficient pattern to avoid such suituations and guarantee that remote system will always follow up on new log entries? In single-consumer scenario an explicit acknowledgement of every individual event is a viable option, but are there any solutions that will ensure consistent event readout order in multi-consumer scenario where you cannot store explicit acknowledgements?

Comment: Don't rely on the id range and add a status column?

Comment: @mustaccio, as I mentioned, this is a viable option when you have just a single consumer per event. But suppose that you are publishing an event stream for indefinite amount of subscribers, e.g. just a public endpoint which could be used by anyone.

Comment: So you're saying consumers maintain their own status independently of each other? Then use the tool that's intended for the job, i.e. a pub-sub engine.